# Insert INTO a table combining * with a column value

Tags: mysql, insert

In MySQL, I am trying to insert all values from table A to table B, but I need to change the structure of table B and a column where all the values would be 0.

Is it possible to mix and create such a query as below, or what could be the possible query for this case?!
Many thanks.

```
$limitid = 50;
$pr1 = "INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A where A.id > $limitid ;
//to get 
$pr1 = "INSERT INTO B (*,col10) VALUES(*,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
$pr1 = "INSERT INTO B SELECT *, 0 col10 FROM A where A.id > $limitid"
```

But this code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection**  so use only **prepared statemenst with parameters** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: So many thanks. it works very well, Thank you also for further infoamtion about sql injection.